# How do you solve for continuous random variable CDF's?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I came down with the flu and missed a stats class. I decided to get a head start on the homework in case I had any questions and got stumped on the first question and I didn't find any good explanations online... Before going through the trouble of finding office hours that coincide with mine, I'm hoping someone here can give me a good explanation. I know that F(x) = P(X=x) = Integral(f(x))dx and a few of the other basic formulas from the lecture slides, but I'm very confused on how to implement them. I am not explicitly looking for the answers to these questions, but an explanation of how to use the formulas to solve them since I have like another 30 to do. I don't understand which numbers get plugged in where...

Suppose that f (x) = e^-(x-6.4) for 6.4 < x and f (x) = 0 for x ≤ 6.4. Determine the following probabilities.

(a)P(X > 6.4)
(b)P(6.4 ≤ X < 8.5)
(c)P(X < 8.5)
(d)P(X > 8.5)
(e) Determine x such that P(X < x) = 0.958.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is the density function, then 
$$\Pr(X\le x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t_\,dt.$$
Using this, we can show that
$$\Pr(a\lt x\le b)=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt.$$
One thing to remember is that if $X$ has continuous distribution, then for any point $c$, we have $\Pr(X=c)=0$. Another thing to remember is that we need not worry about any region where the density function is $0$.

Now we tackle the problems.

(a) $\Pr(X\gt 6.4) =\int_{6.4}^\infty e^{-(t-6.4)}\,dt$. I expect you can compute integrals. If you have any trouble, make the substitution $u=t-6.4$.

The answer will be $1$. This is because we are integrating the density function over the whole interval where it is $\ne 0$.

(b) We need $\int_{6.4}^{8.5} e^{-(t-6.4)}\, dt$.

(c) Integrate from $6.4$ to $8.5$. Same integral, same answer as in (b).

(d) In principle, this is $\int_{8.5}^\infty e^{-(t-6.4)}\,dt$. However, let $A$ be the event $X\lt 8.5$ and let $B$ be the event $X\gt 8.5$. These two events are disjoint, and their union is almost the whole space. The only thing missing is $8.5$. But the probability that $X=8.5$ is $0$. Thus $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)=1$, and therefore $\Pr(B)=1-\Pr(A)$. Thus the answer is $1$ minus the answer in (c).

(e) We want $\int_{6.4}^x e^{-(t-6.4)}\,dt=0.958$.

Integrate. We get $1-e^{x-6.4}$. Set this equal to $0.958$. Algebra gives $e^{-(x-6.4)}=0.042$. Take the natural logarithm of both sides.

We get $-(x-6.4)\approx -3.17$. solve for $x$.